# Javascript AddtoCart code not working

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, object, tampermonkey

I am trying to create essentially a bot that can add a product on Foot Action to my cart. I have this code but it does not work. Can anybody debug it and just explain what I've done incorrectly. My browser is Chrome and I use TamperMonkey.
 This an example of the product page:
[Footaction product](http://www.footaction.com/product/model:203675/sku:16175700/nike-lebron-xi-mens/gold/olive-green/?cm=GLOBAL%20SEARCH%3A%20KEYWORD%20SEARCH#sku=16175700&size=13.0)

```
window.addEventListener('load'
, function() {

var added = false;

function interval1(){
    return  window.setInterval(function(){
            if(document.getElementById("addToCart") !=  null){
                added = true;
                window.location = "http://www.footaction.com/checkout/";
            }
            else if(added == false){
                var cartbtn = document.getElementById("addToCartLink");
                cartbtn.click();
            }
        }, 1000);
}

var id1 = interval1();

window.setInterval(function(){
    if(added == true){
        window.clearInterval(id1);
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: For errors in Javascript, you should first use your browser's developer tools yourself and see where that takes you, and if nowhere, report your findings. If this is a syntax error as PAPAFRESH's answer indicates, you'd have had a more or less clear error message saying to there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you are missing the last **closing squiggly bracket** for window.load event

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

var added = false;

function interval1(){
return  window.setInterval(function(){
        if(document.getElementById("addToCart") !=  null){
            added = true;
            window.location = "http://www.footaction.com/checkout/";
        }
        else if(added == false){
            var cartbtn = document.getElementById("addToCartLink");
            cartbtn.click();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

var id1 = interval1();

window.setInterval(function(){
   if(added == true){
    window.clearInterval(id1);
   }
}, 100);

}; // you were missing this line .. the ending squiggly bracket
```